# Spark Streaming Kafka Timeout

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to run Spark + Kafka integration on Amazon EMR with a simple example with spark-shell but i keep getting time out errors. However, when I publish with `org.apache.kafka` and same settings as below it works without failure.

Time out error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

I moved `client.truststore.jks` and `client.keystore.p12` to hdfs and ran the below

```
$ spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0
```

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val kafkaOptions = Map("kafka.bootstrap.servers" -> s"$host:$port",
        "kafka.security.protocol" -> "SSL",
        "kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm" -> "",
        "kafka.ssl.truststore.location" -> "/home/hadoop/client.truststore.jks",
        "kafka.ssl.truststore.password" -> "password",
        "kafka.ssl.keystore.type" -> "PKCS12",
        "kafka.ssl.key.password" -> "password",
        "kafka.ssl.keystore.location" -> "/home/hadoop/client.keystore.p12",
        "kafka.ssl.keystore.password" -> "password")
    )

 val df = spark
        .read
        .option("header", true)
        .option("escape", "\"")
        .csv("s3://bucket/file.csv")

 val publishToKafkaDf = df.withColumn("value", col("body"))

 publishToKafkaDf
      .selectExpr( "CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .write
      .format("kafka")
      .option("topic", "test-topic")
      .options(kafkaOptions)
      .save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was an AWS security group outbound issue with worker nodes